# How many spell slots does a multiclassed Cleric (4 levels)/Fighter (Eldritch Knight) (1 level) have?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

Okay, I'm trying to figure out the number of spell slots a character should have that has 4 levels of Cleric and 1 level of Fighter with the Eldritch Knight Martial Archetype, and my interpretation and [OrcPub](http://www.orcpub.com/dungeons-and-dragons/5th-edition/character/generator) disagree.

> ***Spell Slots.*** You determine your available spell slots by adding together all your levels in the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes, and a third of your fighter or rogue levels (rounded down) if you have the Eldritch Knight or the Arcane Trickster feature. Use this total to determine your spell slots by consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table.
>
> ~ PHB, p164

So, my calculation goes like this:

- Fighter level 1 adds 0: `1/3 round down = 0`
- Cleric level 4 = adds 4: `4 = 4`
- Total is 4: `4 + 0 = 4`

So then consulting the relevant table:

> **Multiclass Spellcaster:**
>
> **Spell Slots per Spell Level**
>
> ```
>   Lvl.   1st    2nd    3rd
>   1st     2      -      -
>   2nd     3      -      -
>   3rd     4      2      -
>   4th     4      3      -
>   5th     4      3      2
> ```
>
> ~PHB p.165

I get that I should have four 1st level spell slots, three 2nd level spell slots, and no 3rd level spells.

But when you plug the same starting conditions into [OrcPub](http://www.orcpub.com/dungeons-and-dragons/5th-edition/character/generator), it says I should have four 1st level spell slots, three 2nd level spell slots, and two 3rd level spell slots.

---

Whose math is wrong? And if it's mine, can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is what you get from it intentionally shown as if it were the third level values instead of the fourth level values?

Comment: Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are a 4th level caster from cleric levels alone. In addition, you get a +0 on your Fighter level (until you become an EK at Cleric 4/Fighter 3). This means your Multiclass spellcaster level is 4.

According to the chart you listed above, you should have 4 first level spells, and 3 second level spells, but 0 third level spells.

Orcpub seems outdated at this point, as they have released a new version at [www.orcpub2.com](http://www.orcpub2.com/) . This version does not have the same error you are experiencing with the older version.