# Multi Classing Spell Level

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, character-levels, caster-level

Ok I know people are going to tell me to look at the PHB but I am having a debate with the DM on how the multiclass table works specifically with fighter/rogue

If a person is fighter5/wizard1 would they be a lvl 2 spell caster because its Floor(5/3) = 1 + 1(wizard) = 2

or is it...

round up as you do most times
5/3 = 2 + 1(wizard) = 3

Comment: There are previous questions on this kind of issue, see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79573/how-do-paladin-and-ranger-class-levels-add-up-for-multiclass-spellcasting?rq=1) and [there](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106905/how-many-spell-slots-does-a-multiclassed-cleric-4-levels-fighter-eldritch-kni?rq=1)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151000/if-i-multiclass-into-2-or-more-spellcasting-classes-how-do-i-determine-my-known)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The correct level is 2 if your character is an Eldritch Knight, 1 otherwise.

Each level of wizard counts as a full spellcaster level when multiclassing. Each fighter level counts as a third of a level but only if you have the Eldritch Knight class feature. Fractional levels are **rounded down** as is the general rule (Player's Handbook, page 7) and as is also explicitly stated in the multiclassing rules (Player's Handbook, page 164). To be absolutely clear, one **always** rounds down in DnD 5e, unless a feature specifically tells you to round up.

Five levels divided by three, rounded down, is one level. Add your wizard level, and you get a caster level of 2. If your character is not an Eldritch Knight, then only the wizard level is counted.