# How many spell slots should a Fighter 11/Ranger 9 have?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, ranger, fighter, spell-slots

I've been DM for like 2-3 months and one player who's playing a Fighter (arcane archer) wants to multiclass into Ranger. Arcane Archer is not a spellcaster so assuming he will go Fighter 11/Ranger 9 how many spellslots should he get as 9th lvl Ranger. Should it be 4/3/2 or 4/2 only? I don't know too much about multiclassing yet so guys help.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I've edited you question to make it a bit clearer, if you disagree feel free to edit it further or revert the edit. Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate [How many spell slots should my level 1 wizard/level 1 fighter have?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144594/how-many-spell-slots-should-my-level-1-wizard-level-1-fighter-have)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### That character should have spell slots of a 9th level Ranger: 4/3/2

The multiclassing rules for spellcasters is only invoked once you have more than one class which gives you the spellcasting feature. The relevant excerpt from the multiclassing rules:

> Once you have the Spellcasting feature from more than one
>   class, use the rules below. If you multiclass but have the
>   Spellcasting feature from only one class, you follow the
>   rules as described in that class.
>
> --- *Player's Handbook* p. 164